# How to Enable Google Adsense Host API for Testing

Tags: ads, adsense, adsense-api

I'm doing research regarding Google Adsense Host API on how to split the revenue of ads between the content creators and website's owner. I've been following the instruction at https://developers.google.com/adsense/host/getting_started?authuser=3 where I was able to successfully create an Adsense Account.

But when I trigger this request:
https://www.googleapis.com/adsensehost/v4.1/associationsessions/start.

I got this error:

```
Customer is not an AdSense Host.
```

I've read that the website needs 100K views/day but obviously since this is R&D and the Adsense account is new, it doesn't have that amount of views.

Is there a way to particularly test this API without the 100k/day views requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer, but: the AdSense Host API is now in maintenance mode, so it won't be accepting any new partners; it has been replaced by [AdSense for Platforms](https://developers.devsite.corp.google.com/adsense/platforms).

Comment: Thanks. This must be hidden as I haven't chanced upon it even after all that searching :-)